# consuming json to model using java

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jax-rs

People, I need help, if anyone can help me, I thank you!

I am getting a JSON and wanted to know if I can bring the information to a LIST of my model.

is a call to send 1 SMS

This is the first time I try to do something with JSON

my model has all getters and setters.

Model

```
public class Zenvia {

@JsonProperty("sendSmsResponse")
private String sendSmsResponse;

//Request
@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("from")
private String from;
@JsonProperty("to")
private String to;
@JsonProperty("msg")
private String msg;
@JsonProperty("schedule")
private String schedule;
@JsonProperty("callbackOption")
private String callbackOption;
@JsonProperty("aggregateId")
private String aggregateId;
@JsonProperty("flashSms")
private boolean flashSms;

//Response
private long stats;
@JsonProperty("statusCode")
private String statusCode;
@JsonProperty("statusDescription")
private String statusDescription;
@JsonProperty("detailCode")
private String detailCode;
@JsonProperty("detailDescription")
private String detailDescription;
@JsonProperty("mobileOperatorName")
private String mobileOperatorName;
@JsonProperty("received")
private String received;

//getters and setters
}
```

my call

```
public Zenvia senderUnique(Zenvia zenvia) {

        Response response = null;
        try {

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            Entity payload = Entity.json("    {\n"
                    + "        \"sendSmsRequest\": {\n"
                    + "            \"from\": \"" + zenvia.getFrom() + "\",\n"
                    + "            \"to\": \"" + zenvia.getTo() + "\",\n"
                    + "            \"schedule\": \"" + zenvia.getSchedule() + "\",\n"
                    + "            \"msg\": \"" + zenvia.getMsg() + "\",\n"
                    + "            \"callbackOption\": \"" + zenvia.getCallbackOption() + "\",\n"
                    + "            \"id\": \"" + zenvia.getId() + "\",\n"
                    + "            \"aggregateId\": \"" + zenvia.getAggregateId() + "\",\n"
                    + "            \"flashSms\": " + zenvia.isFlashSms() + "\n"
                    + "        }\n"
                    + "    }");

            response = client.target("https://api-rest.zenvia360.com.br/services/send-sms")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic ***********")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .post(payload);

            System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
            System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
            System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));

            response.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return zenvia;
    }
```

at this point I have this return, which is the best practice of consuming this data, I have a model prepared to receive this information.

converting to a LIST?
as?

```
string JSON response that im getting

        body:{
  "sendSmsMultiResponse" : {
    "sendSmsResponseList" : [ {
      "statusCode" : "10",
      "statusDescription" : "Error",
      "detailCode" : "080",
      "detailDescription" : "Message with same ID already sent"
    }, {
      "statusCode" : "10",
      "statusDescription" : "Error",
      "detailCode" : "080",
      "detailDescription" : "Message with same ID already sent"
    }, {
      "statusCode" : "10",
      "statusDescription" : "Error",
      "detailCode" : "080",
      "detailDescription" : "Message with same ID already sent"
    } ]
  }
}
```

can be one or more results, so is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the response to a `String` and then `Map` it to your `Entity` class using `jackson`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = response.readEntity(String.class);

//Convert JSON from String to Object
List<YourEntityModelObject> objList = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, new TypeReference<List<YourEntityModelObject>>(){});
```

Comment: i add this code in my code and now im having an error - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: can you add your `Entity` Model class here and the string `JSON` response that you are getting. The above code snippet is for one entity and will fail for `List`

Comment: Please share your Entity class also

Comment: i use this model Zenvia.class with JDBC connection, i dont use hibernate

Comment: I have updated the answer to support a List, you should split your `Zenvia` class into `ZenviaRequest` and `ZenviaResponse` and have another Model class `ZenziaMultiResponse` which contains `List< ZenviaResponse>` this should have `@JsonProperty("sendSmsMultiResponse")` also use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` for all classes so that if the WebService send any additional `JSON` mapping your implementation doesn't break. This way you define your mapping according to the `JSON` response you are receiving. Hope this helps.